# Syntax error while creating table in PostgreSQL 8.1

Tags: postgresql

I have a syntax error in this query:

```
CREATE TABLE test (LIKE original_table INCLUDING INDEXES);
```

> ERROR : syntax error at or near "INDEXES"

I am using PostgreSQL 8.1 version. Where is the issue in my query?

Comment: Why you are you using such an outdated version? You should _really_ upgrade to a version that is under maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PostgreSQL 8.1 only supports `INCLUDING DEFAULTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createtable.html).

You'll either have to upgrade to at least 8.3 or create the indices manually.